# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am new to the android development field. I am trying to create NavigationDrawerFragment.

Please help me solve this error:
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

```
package nikita.materialtst;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME="testpref";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="user_learned_drawer";
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private View containerView;

private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserLearnedDrawer=Boolean.valueOf( readFromPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
       mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
}

public void setUp(int fragmentId , DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView=getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout= drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
          if(!mUserLearnedDrawer){
              mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
              saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
          }

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    if(!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState){
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
    }

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

}
public static  void saveToPreferences(Context context,String preferenceName,String preferenceValue){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName,preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}


public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName,defaultValue);
}
```

}

**Log**

```
Process: nikita.materialtst, PID: 8089
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nikita.materialtst/nikita.materialtst.MainActivity}:    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at nikita.materialtst.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:53)
at nikita.materialtst.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
03-03 20:53:03.511 8089-8089/nikita.materialtst I/Process: Sending signal.     PID: 8089 SIG: 9
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package nikita.materialtst;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

private Toolbar toolbar;
private MainActivity mainActivity;
private Class<SubMaterialTst> subMaterialTstClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView tv_login= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_login);
    EditText et_email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    EditText et_password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView tv_registerLink= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_registerLink);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv_registerLink.setOnClickListener(this);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment =new NavigationDrawerFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout),toolbar);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Profile.class) );
            break;

        case R.id.tv_registerLink:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubMaterialTst.class) );
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id=item.getItemId();
    if(id== R.menu.menu_main) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you just clicked option settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

       if(id==R.id.navigate){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubMaterialTst.class) );

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: please share your log

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted. There's no chance an activity you're calling `findViewById()` on is null here. Guessing you have something like `getActivity().findViewById()` in your fragment and it's called too early before the fragment is attached.

Comment: Where is your  view? in fragment or in activity?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: `containerView=getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);`

The view is not found. Please check this variable `fragmentId`, so what you pass to this method: `public void setUp(int fragmentId , DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar)`

Comment: I am not sure how to fix it.. as i am a beginer, please help me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already said, the code is not the issue here. Is the fact that sometimes, when you're declaring the View as on this example containerView, this is not synchronized, and when you're running the app, it throws this exception. To get rid of this all you need is to refactor the code and run the app again.